# How do we rename a rpm build?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I wanted to change the name of my rpm file from oldname-7.x86_64.rpm to newname-8.x86_64.rpm. 
I created the new rpm with the new name but when I try to execute

`rpm -Uvh newname-8.x86_64.rpm`

it throws the following error:

```
file XXXXX from install of oldname-7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package newname-8.x86_64.
```

rpm upgrade removes the package and install the new package. But in my case package name is different so it is not removing the package.
Should I remove the oldname project using rpm -e oldname in the %pre section? Is there any way to set the old name in the %pre section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `Obsoletes` and/or `Provides` tags in your spec file of newname.spec:

```
Obsoletes: oldname
```

and optionally even:

```
Provides: oldname = %{version}-%{release}
```

You can read http://rpm.org/user_doc/dependencies.html for further reference.

Comment: It is not working with Obsoletes. Getting error: %pre(newname-7.0-0.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
error:   install: %pre scriptlet failed (2), skipping newname-7.0-0.

Comment: please read the error: it says there is an error in you `%pre` section; so please correct what is in the `%pre` section of your spec file.

Comment: PS: the `Obsoletes` and `Provides` parts should go on top of your header file, not in the `%pre` section

Comment: I cannot use Provides as it is not sure whether they already installed oldname. Sometimes they directly install newname then this case won't work

Comment: That is not how provides works, but nevermind about that. Just `Obsoletes` should do the trick. Could you show your spec-file in your question?

Comment: It is in the top section. But I am getting an error in %pre section and it shows $1 as 1(Install). When I execute rpm -Uvh newname-8.x86_64.rpm it checks for newname and it is not present so it tries to execute Install instead of Upgrade.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176106/discussion-between-chris-maes-and-sandy).

Comment: Obsoletes works but it is uninstalling after installing the new package. Is there any way to uninstall the old package and then install new package?

Comment: "Obsoletes" uninstalls the old one after installation because that is the [standard ordering of package upgrades](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-rpm2/index.html).